# JUnit/Selenium throwing error for driver.manage().window().maximize()

Tags: java, junit, selenium-webdriver

Code:

```
 if (driverType.equals("firefox")) {
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
   }
```

Error:

```
[javac]   symbol:   method window()
[javac]   location: interface Options
[javac]   java:55: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]   driver.manage().window().maximize();
[javac]                  ^
```

I am using Selenium 2.33.0 version jar, i have all libraries dont know why its throwing above error.

Comment: this code i working fine with me project, but i am not using junit. i am working with selenium web driver.

Comment: Can you show your code where `driverType` gets set?

Comment: I facing a similar problem. Are you using maven?